# Managing timeouts for Nginx and PHP

Tags: php, nginx, timeout

I would like the default timeout for my API to be 60 seconds. But for some endpoints I would like the flexibility to add a few seconds to the timeout duration.

I can do this in PHP like so -  `ini_set('max_execution_time', '120');`.

So to achieve this I want to set Nginx timeout to 300 seconds (5 minutes) and as mentioned the default timeout for PHP to 60 seconds.

I was just wondering whether there are any dangerous downsides to this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that :

```
$time = 60 * 4;
ini_set('max_execution_time', $time);
set_time_limit($time);
```

for each endpoint you want a different timeout

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually just want to understand whether there are any possible dangers to this approach.

- Nginx - 5 minutes
- PHP - 1 minute

I couldn't find a way to increase timeout duration programmatically in Nginx. So extending the timeout in Nginx seems like the sensible thing to do. Then for specific instances I can increase the 60 second default timeout via PHP.

Comment: There is no downside, just don't set it to zero or a very high value